# Destructor when derived class contains a pointer to base class object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor

I have written a pure virtual destructor and implemented it in the abstract base class and override it in derived classes.

However, in one of the classes I have a pointer to a base class object.
Now, should the destructor of the derived class be written this way:

```
virtual ~DerivedClass()
{
delete this->pointerToAnotherDerivedClassObject;
}
```

or will the object be deleted automatically? As the base class destructor is always called so I cannot decide whether it takes care of it or not.

**EDIT:** My mistake for stating it was a pointer to a base class, as it is actually a pointer for another derived class object.

Comment: Sounds like a serious design flaw. Does the derived class actually own the base class instance?

Comment: I have not written this code from scratch, it was handed to me half way through in this state.

Comment: Is it a pointer to yourself, or a separate base class object? ie, `pointerToBaseClassObject=(Base*)this;` or `pointerToBaseClassObject=other`.

Comment: It's exactly the virtual destructors work to do that for you... No need to "delete" this (which would be bad if object wasnt allocated with new, which is very probable)

Comment: @cocarin I edited the question. it is a pointer to a dynamically allocated object of another derived class (they both have the same base class if that matters).

Comment: @Elia Then if you own the object, you need to delete it before you finish destructing. If you have a non-owning reference, you should not delete the object. The C++11 way to do this is to use a smart pointer, such as a shared_ptr that will do that for you.

Comment: Oh, then it's perfect, expect "this->"

Comment: @cocarin I do own the object.

Comment: @BlackMoses are you saying I should make the "delete this->object;" call?

Comment: No, of course not. That would be bad. It's good, but you don't need to write "this->" before variable name. It's by default. It's enough to write `delete pointerToAnotherDerivedClassObject;`

Comment: @BlackMoses Ah yea, bad habit. Thanks.

Comment: Wow this question is getting down voted to hell.. It's a legitimate question for gods sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in one of the classes I have a pointer to a base class object.
>    Now, should the destructor of the derived class be written this way

Since `pointerToAnotherDerivedClassObject` points at *another* object in memory, then yes, your `DerivedClass` destructor needs to explicitly `delete` that object (or wrap the raw pointer inside a smart pointer - `std::auto_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::shared_ptr` - and let it `delete` the object for you) *ONLY IF* `DerivedClass` is meant to own that other object.  Otherwise, do not `delete` it if you do not own it.

Comment: This is exactly the case. And yes, it is meant to own that other object.

Answer (score 0):

@Elia Similar situation is discussed in the book of Eckel " thinking in C++  vol-2 " in design pattern chapter-10 regarding pseudo virtual constructor. The answer to your question is you do need to delete it considering you allocate it dynamically. Also don't confuse member Base* with the Base object which is part of derived due to inheritance, one is a data member (which is what you want to delete) other is due to inheritance.